# Datatables inside child row of parent datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I try to create datatable inside child row of parent datatable. Source in parent datatable is from DOM, and source of nested datatable is also from DOM generated when child row is shown.

**Child datatable doesn't work.**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var table = $('#table_emissions').DataTable(); 

$('#table_emissions tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var row = table.row( tr );

    if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
        // This row is already open - close it
        row.child.hide();
        tr.removeClass('shown');
    }
    else {
        // Open this row
        row.child( getAjaxEmission(row.data()) ).show();
        tr.addClass('shown');
        var subtable = $('#table_messages_' + row.data().id).DataTable();
    }
} ); 
} );
```

**JS functions for creating child DOM code:**

```
function getAjaxEmission ( d ) {
var div = $('<div/>')
 .addClass( 'loading' )
 .text( 'Učitavanje...' ); 

 $.ajax( {
     type: "GET",
     url: '/api/ntxEmission/' + d.id,
     success: function ( json ) {
         div
             .html(formatNtxEmission(json.data))
             .removeClass( 'loading' );
     }
 } );
return div;
}

function formatNtxEmission( m ) {
return '<div class="container" id="container_messages">' + 
'<table class="table table-bordered table-striped display" id="table_messages_' + m.id +'">' + 
    '<thead class="thead-inverse">'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<th></th>'+
            '<th>Id</th>'+                          
            '<th>Oznaka</th>'+
            '<th>Vrijeme prvog emitiranja</th>'+
            '<th>Vrijeme zadnjeg emitiranja</th>'+
            '<th>Broj emitiranja</th>'+
        '</tr>'+
    '</thead>'+
    '<tbody>'+
        formatListNtxMessages(m.transmittedMessages) + 
    '</tbody>'+
'</table>'+
'</div>';
}
```

> Table in child row is created OK, but is not formated as datatable.

Comment: You got to do it after `ajax - success`. `ajax` call is `asynchronous`. and hence your line of initializing `datatable` will be performed before the `ajax` call is completed and hence the `datatable` is not initalized on newly appended `data`. Either you need to have a `callback` on `ajax` function or there has to be someway provided by `datatable` to get `row` details via `ajax`.

Comment: add  $('#table_messages_' + row.data().id).DataTable(); in success method of ajax.

Comment: Thank you. Resolved. Both of you was correct.

Comment: My child datatable disappears once I inovke on the child id :(